# Total paid function

Tags: python, credit-card

I have this code:

```
balance = 4213
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04
monthly_interest_rate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
for counter in range(1, 12):
    payment = monthlyPaymentRate * balance
    monthly_unpaid_balance = balance - payment
    balance = monthly_unpaid_balance + (monthly_interest_rate * monthly_unpaid_balance)
    print('Month: {}\nMinimum monthly payment: {}\nRemaining balance:{}'.format(
              counter, round(payment, 2), round(balance, 2)))
```

How can I calculate Total paid(sum of all minimum monthly payments)?

Comment: 'Please help me with this part of the code.' Which part?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are calculating for only 11 months instead of 12.

```
for counter in range(1, 12+1)
```

Comment: I've allocated my problem with ** sings

Answer (score 1):

You copy-pasted wrongly from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19743782/371834). The range should be until `13`.

Comment: Oh, God. You're right....